# rsync copy folder hierarchy but only files in last folder

Tags: php, copy, exec, rsync

I wonder if this is possible. Basically, I am trying to write a very basic script to help me speed up the upgrade process of several installs of a CMS system (where I need to copy across certain folders).

So let's say I have a folder:

```
/home/sites/domain.co.uk/public_html/folder1/folder2/files
```

What I need to do is copy the folder tree and only copy the files in the files folder.

At the moment I am using rsync -a via:

```
<?php
exec("rsync -a /home/sites/domain.co.uk/public_html/folder1/folder2/files /home/sites/domain.co.uk/copy");
?>
```

The problem with this is instead of creating the following:

```
/home/sites/domain.co.uk/copy/folder1/folder2/files
```

it creates

```
/home/sites/domain.co.uk/copy/files
```

Is there a way to use rsync to copy the previous folders / structure as well so I end up with?

```
/home/sites/domain.co.uk/copy/folder1/folder2/files
```

I'm quite happy to use rsync as opposed to creating a full php script etc

Answer (score 0):

functionality of rsync is to transfer files from one location to another OR from one server to another(if you have root access to other folder)
In your following example

```
<?php
exec("rsync -a /home/sites/domain.co.uk/public_html/folder1/folder2/files /home/sites/domain.co.uk/copy");
?>
```

There must be `files` folder on your server at given path which contains files and in `copy` folder all those files will be transferred.

instead you can try below command to transfer your files

```
<?php
exec("rsync -auv -e ssh --progress /home/sites/domain.co.uk/public_html/folder1/folder2/files /home/sites/domain.co.uk/copy");
?>
```

`--progress`  will show which file is being transferred.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Just to clarify, the code I mentioned above works but it doesn't copy the folder structure before the 'files' folder. I'm not sure how using auv -e will combat this? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `but it doesn't copy the folder structure before the 'files' folder.` rsync command is not to create folder rather its for coping